# How to override property setter in a subclass of a Cython extension type

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I have a Python module which defines class A with subclass B. Class A defines a property with a getter and setter, class B overrides the setter:

```
import abc

class A:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class A")
        self.__x = newX

class B(A):
    @A.x.setter
    def x(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class B")
        A.x.fset(self, newX)

b = B()
b.x = 42
print(b.x)
```

When I let Cython compile the module and then import it, Python prints the desired output:

```
Setter in class B
Setter in class A
42
```

Running it as a pure Python module (without Cython compilation) also gives me the desired output.

For performance reasons, I'd like to turn A into an extension type by changing line 3 to:

```
cdef class A:
```

With this, Cython compilation remains possible, but then I get this exception at runtime:
File "test.pyx", line 21, in init test
@A.x.setter
AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'setter'

Is there a different way to override the setter, so that it also works with a cdef class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For performance reasons, I'd like to turn A into an extension type [...]

One thing worth emphasising - by using a `cdef class` you are trading flexibility for performance so this sort of thing not working is expected.

What I'd do in this case is have the setter in `A` call an implementation function, and override the implementation function in `B`. If `B` is a `cdef class` then the implementation function can be `cdef`. Otherwise it needs to be `cpdef` (or `def`):

```
cdef class A:
    ...

    @x.setter
    def x(self, newX):
        self.xSettingImpl(newX)

    cpdef xSetterImpl(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class A")
        self.__x = newX

class B:
    def xSetterImpl(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class B")
        A.x.fset(self, newX)  # Not sure this is likely to work though...
```

---

Also, I don't think this will work in a `cdef class`:

```
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right, the "__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta" would not stop me from creating an instance of A.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77806012/10263958 for the solution that I could implement thanks to DavidW's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802386/10263958 from DavidW, I was able to come up with this solution:

```
cdef class A:
    __x: int = 0

    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Tried to instantiate abstract class A.")

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, newX):
        self.xSetterImpl(newX)

    def xSetterImpl(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class A")
        self.__x = newX

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def xSetterImpl(self, newX):
        print("Setter in class B")
        A.xSetterImpl(self, newX)

b = B()
b.x = 23
print(b.x)
```